# Is it possible to send bearer access token through webhooks? If not how can I do it through code?

Tags: node.js, zapier

I have following code in nodejs, but zapier doesnot support request module. 
Using fetch or standard http method, can this be implemented in my zap?

```js
request(
  {
    url: "https://wechat.com/",
    auth: {
      bearer: accessToken
    }
  },
  function(err, res) {
    //do something
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Yeah, this is pretty straightforward with `fetch`.

You need to set the `Authentication` header to `bearer mytoken`:

```js
const myToken = "ABCD";

const response = await fetch("https://self.wavity.net/scim/doc/", {
  headers: { Authentication: `bearer ${myToken}` }
});
```

You can also use the `base-64` library to encode the token if you need as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842793/basic-authentication-with-fetch).

Comment: How do i send json data in fetch

Comment: I'd check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data