# how to pass basic authentication in api call in react native using asynch await fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to call the basic authentication rest api in the react native.how to pass basic authentication headers.getting error - unhandled promise rejection - cant find base64 variable

```
  getDataFromAPI=async()=>
{

  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.encode("admin:admin@123"));
  const endpoint='url'
  const res=await fetch (endpoint,{headers:headers})
  const data=await res.json()
  this.setState({items:data})
}
  _renderItem=({item,index})=>{
    let{cardText,card,cardImage}= styles
return  (
  <TouchableOpacity style={card}>
          <Text style={cardText}>{item.id} Reactor Status:  {item.ph}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic authentication with fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842793/basic-authentication-with-fetch)

Comment: fetch takes a second argument so that you can pass custom headers

Comment: what exactly is your error or what do you want other than what you have achieved?

Comment: getting error - possible unhandled promise rejection - cant find variable base64

Comment: it says the base64 is not defiend, are you defining it somewhere, perhaps its a package ? @GauravRoy

Answer (score 0):

installed 
npm i -S base-64
and imported 
import {decode as atob, encode as btoa} from 'base-64'

and i got the response from the basic authentication rest api in react native code

```
getDataFromAPI=async()=>
{

  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("admin:admin@123"));
  const endpoint='url'
  const res=await fetch (endpoint,{headers:headers})
  const data=await res.json()
  this.setState({items:data})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it depends on what authentication method you are using at server side but as of above code you can try below

```
    fetch("https://www.majhgaon.com/app/supplier/add_report", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              "key-name": "kay-value",
            },
          body: JSON.stringify({
                  ....
               }) 
          })
```