# Client secret & id to be deprecated in the coming months

Tags: javascript, github-api, fetch-api

My code works but the request format will be deprecated in the coming months.

**New format suggested from [Github](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/)**

```
curl -u my_client_id:my_client_secret https://api.github.com/users/user
```

Can someone show me the correct way to reformat it for when it is deprecated in the coming months. I've tried everything. Here is one example of what I've tried:

**My attempt that doesn't work**

```
`-u ${this.client_id}:${this.client_secret} https://api.github.com/users/${user}`
```

**My current code**

```js
class Github {
  constructor() {
    // THESE ARE FAKE!!!
    this.client_id = 'a71344259aec03d0cea3';
    this.client_secret = 'a28202377336e199cb554bd099e6e5fe672788db';
    this.repos_count = 7;
    this.repos_sort = 'created: asc';
  }

  async getUser(user) {
    const profileResponse = await fetch(
      `https://api.github.com/users/${user}?client_id=${this.client_id}&client_secret=${this.client_secret}`
    );

    const repoResponse = await fetch(
      `https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos?per_page=${this.repos_count}&sort=${this.repos_sort}&client_id=${this.client_id}&client_secret=${this.client_secret}`
    );
    console.log(user);

    const profile = await profileResponse.json();
    const repos = await repoResponse.json();

    return {
      profile,
      repos,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: that format is auth basic see: [Basic authentication with fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842793/basic-authentication-with-fetch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-u` option in `curl` uses [HTTP Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side).

What this does is takes the `user:password` string, base64-encodes it (eg `user:password` => `dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==`) and adds it to the `Authorization` request header like this

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

When using `fetch`, you have to do this manually using something like [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa)

```js
const auth = btoa(`${this.client_id}:${this.client_secret}`)

fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${encodeURIComponent(user)}`, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic ${auth}`
  }
})
```