Fetch with basic authentication works with Postman but not in Javascript
I would like to access the Windows Device Portal Api (access the Api of a connected Hololens 2 on the same network of the client) but I kept getting a Network Request Failed from Javascript.
The fact is, that request is working well on Postman, but, even when I am stupidly copying the example JavaScript code from Postman, it still doesn't work.
The result on Postman:
{
    "ComputerName": "HoloLens2-05",
    "Language": "en-US",
    "OsEdition": "Holographic",
    "OsEditionId": 136,
    "OsVersion": "22621.1272.arm64fre.ni_release_svc_sydney_rel_prod.240403-0940",
    "Platform": "HoloLens 2"
}

Here is my setup:

React Native 0.73
Targeting Android (simulator or device, they both don't work)
IDE: VSCode on Windows

What I did:

Copying the code from Postman:

var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic base64here");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "CSRF-Token=csrfTokenHere");

var raw = "";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://hololensnetworkip/api/os/info", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));


Set the AndroidManifest in android/src/main:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">


Trying the Windows Device Portal suggestion of applying an "auto-" prefix on the login (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal#csrf-protection-and-scripting):


I know the Windows Device Portal facing issues with not valid certificate status, but why is it working on Postman ? Or why is it working with a call from .Net client ?
Thanks anyway for your hints, I'll keep searching on my side.

Your request appears to be cross-origin, so you would need to set the credentials  option for your fetch request appropriately, otherwise it will not send any credentials to begin with.

Hi, thanks for your response. What do you mean by appropriately ? The credentials are the username:password encoded in base64 set in the Authorization header. Do I have to indicate elsewhere my crendentials ? I followed one of those examples to set the Basic Auth and it's the same as indicated in my post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43843163/1845692

I am talking about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials

Hi, thanks for your suggestion ! We tried with the credentials options (like include), it doesn't work either. We succeeded making requests by bypassing the ssl security on the device (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-troubleshooting#workaround-for-device-portal-time-out) but it's not ideal.
